# Problem using qmake with Qt3Support

Tags: qt, qmake

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on an x86_64 cpu. I try to create a Makefile using qmake with the flag QT += Qt3Support, but I get the answer 
"Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: Qt3Support"

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the package libQt3Support.so.4, but I keep getting the same error. The module is installed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.

Is it a linking error or a 64/32 bit problem or else?

/Staffan

Comment: The name is case-sensitive, I think: it needs to be `qt3support`. Also, you may need to use `qmake-qt4` explicitly i.e. `qmake-qt4 "QT += qt3support"`.

Comment: Thank you! The qmake-qt4 command was the trick. And it should also be lower-case letter as you wrote.